# <br> element not working between div and input

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks, element

Below is the code that I am using. For some reason I cannot get the br in between the div.chatBox and input to show. Can anyone give me any suggestions.

```
<div class="container-fluid col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <br>
        <div class="chatBox col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3" id="chatBox">
        </div>

        <br>

        <input type="text" class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"The br to show"_ - what do you mean? If you need space between `div` use CSS margins. `br` is a line break for text.

Comment: you are usig class  row  .. in bootstrap this mean  keep the content on the same row ..

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: do you mean `hr` ? you can always put a class and modify the styles even in an `hr`

Comment: @evolutionxbox agreed

Comment: @evolutionbox Thank you that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As evolutionxbox says, you have to use css to display corectly your elements.

however your br tag works fine, it's just that your first div is empty, so you do not see the difference, try this two sample, with and without br.

```html
<div class="container-fluid col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <br>
        <div class="chatBox col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3" id="chatBox" style="background-color:red;width:160px;height:100px">
        </div>

        <br/>

        <input type="text" class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <br>
        <div class="chatBox col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3" id="chatBox" style="background-color:red;width:160px;height:100px">
        </div>

        

        <input type="text" class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped me understand why you don't see the changes on the page thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

My class was bootstrap, so all I done was add an id, like:

```
<div class="col-lg-12"  id="bottom_row_home">
```

and then inside my css, I used

```
#bottom_row_home {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

This gave me a little space between the two div rows.

Answer (score 0):

According to bootstrap guidieline your `div` elements should have a `row` class.
 And then you could just add styles as margin of 1em for them instead of using breaklines.

Answer (score -2):

The way you have used  `<br/>` tag will have no effect as `<div>` is already a block element, that's the reason, you are feeling that `<br>` tag is not working.

If you want to add some space then use `&nbsp;`

Comment: `<input>` is NOT a block element